# Loop through dates Mac OSX Terminal Bash

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I am looking to execute a python script from terminal (Mac OSX). The python script takes two dates (a beginning and an end date). The 2 arguments need to be one day apart. The current code I am running in terminal is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set beg date
beg= 2012-01-01

# Set a counter variable
counter=1 

# Increase the counter to get back in time
while [ "$beg" != 2020-08-01 ]; do
  echo $beg
  beg=$(beg -v -${counter}d '+%Y-%m-%d')
  end=$(beg -v -${((counter+1))}d '+%Y-%m-%d')
  python fetch_links.py beg end
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

I am getting several errors that are listed below:

```
fetch_links.py: error: argument date_start: end is not a proper date string

-bash: beg: command not found
-bash: -${((counter+1))}d: bad substitution
```

My goal is to start with the beginning date (2012-01-01) pass the beginning date and end date through to the python sript until all daily periods between 2012 and today have been passed. For example, the first iteration should pass through "2012-01-01" as the start and "2012-01-02" as the end date.

Comment: you have an error at `beg= ...` there should be no space between the var, `=`, and the value.

Comment: @arhodes4 : `$(beg -v ....)` invokes a command named `beg`. It seems that you don't have an executable of this name in your PATH. Aside from this, wouldn't it be easier to do the whole date arithmetic completely in Python?

Comment: @arhodes4 : `${((counter+1))}` doesn't make sense either. Do you mean `$((counter+1))` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

```
startdate=2012-01-01
end=2020-08-01
enddate=2012-01-02

sDateTs=`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $startdate "+%s"`
eDateTs=`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $enddate "+%s"`
e1DateTs=`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $end "+%s"`
dateTs=$sDateTs
date1Ts=$eDateTs
offset=86400

while [ "$dateTs" -le "$e1DateTs" ]
do
  date1=`date -j -f "%s" $dateTs "+%Y-%m-%d"`
  date2=`date -j -f "%s" $date1Ts "+%Y-%m-%d"`  
  python fetch_links.py $date1 $date2
  dateTs=$(($dateTs+$offset))
  date1Ts=$(($date1Ts+$offset))
done
```